# How to Copy a Column into Another Table in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

Before I ask the question, I just want to admit that I'm a beginner at MySQL. I've searched for the solution in various places but had no luck. I'm working on a project where there are a particular number of books in the database and all the users that are signed up in the website can access this list of books( these books are common to all users). And the logged in user can put a check-mark beside the listed book if he completes reading it.

I've created tables `users`, `books` and `user_books`. The `user_books` table contains userid(references users table) and bookid(references books table) columns with an *isComplete* boolean column where the actual "check-marks" are stored.

Now what I'm actually looking for is a way to insert the userid(repeated with every book) and the whole column of bookid for each user into the `user_books` table. i.e., if the `books` table has books a, b and c and if a user John registers into the website, the `user_books` table should be updated with ('John', 'a'), ('John', 'b') and ('John', 'c'). This trigger should be applied immediately after the user registers into the website.

Or if there is any other way to achieve this "to-do" functionality for every user and every book, please do mention that.

Comment: Before helping you solving this problem, i have another question to you: How big is your application? Or how big you expect it to be? Will it have 10  users, 100 users, 100'000 users? 10 books? 100 books? 100'000 books? May you'll run in trouble the way you try to do it, depends on how big your app. will be..

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: Okay, lets say your application has 1000 users and 1000 books. You're database will contain 1'000'000 entrys. Thats a lot. I'm just asking this because i don't think that it is a good idea to create a user_books table with all these entrys directly on registration...
Instead you sould only save the read books. 
So you can forgot about this boolean field in your table, all entrys shown in your user_books are entrys that shows that userID has read bookID. That will give you less of trash. But if you only have 10 books and 10 users, you haven't to care about. (Altough it's bad practice)

Comment: I suppose there is no need to that unless your existing application works like that. Just add a record in `user_books` table when user marks the book as completed.

Comment: This isn't required to do in that way. After registration, you can assign them later.

Comment: To add to Suraj's comment, if you're worried about having to look if the user-book entry already exists every time you want to set it, you should look at MySQL's `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html. That way, you can execute a single query to either create the association or update it if it already exists.

Comment: This is just a sample project I wanted to do to study MySQL even more deeper. It's not actually going to be any major web app but I just want to learn to maintain any number of users, no matter how big the number is.

Comment: In that case, your idea is definitely not the way to go. Suppose you have 100,000 users and 100,000 books. That makes 10 billion entries. That's a lot considering most, if not all people, will not have read every single book on your website. So basically the idea would be: everytime a user wants to set a book to "read", you do a `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` query, for instance:  `INSERT INTO user_books(userid, bookid, read) VALUES(<your user id>, <your book id>, <your boolean>) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE read = VALUES(read);`.

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` would work with multiple foreign keys. If it doesn't work, you can still manually check if the association row still exists, by doing a `SELECT * FROM user_books WHERE userid = <user id> AND bookid = <book id>`, and if you get any row, `UPDATE` it, if not, do your `INSERT` statement.